# Console application to download DocuSign envelope documents - auth token

Tags: oauth-2.0, docusignapi, auth-token

I need to create a console app to download all signed docusign documents (envelope by envelope) and then upload all Salesforce environment ... what is the best way to get auth token? it seems that every single way requires redirectUri - which I am working with a console app and i do not have redirectUri.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

JWT only requires a redirect URI for the initial consent call. You do it once, not using your app, but constructing the URI that will give you consent and then you don't need to ever do this again. JWT is probably what you want for this type of app.

Comment: Thanks Inbar!  I found a way to grant app permission from organization panel but I do not know what are the accepted permissions/scopes - signature, extended and impersonate are 3 i found, is there an one called full permission for my case?

Comment: there's no "full" as far as I know and you only need signature and impersonate for what you are building